# Domain of analyticity for $\operatorname{Log}(z^4 - 1)^{1/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I solve for the analyticity of $\operatorname{Log}(z^4 - 1)^{1/2}$?

So I factored out $$z^4 - 1 = x^4 + 4ix^3y - 6x^2y^2 - 4ixy^3 + y^4 - 1$$

Now the $$\operatorname{Re}(z^4 - 1) = x^4 - 6x^2y^2 + y^4 - 1 < 0 \implies x^4 - 6x^2y^2 + y^4 < 1$$ but I'm stuck here on how to find the set where $\operatorname{Re}(z^4 - 1)$ is nonnegative.

$$\operatorname{Im}(z^4 - 1) = 4x^3y - 4xy^3 = 4xy(x^2 - y^2) = 0 \implies x=0, y=0$$ but unsure how to interpret that either, is it only $z=0$ where it is not analytic or on $x=0$ and $y=0$ axis?

If anyone knows a textbook reference that clearly explains these concepts that would be great as well.

Comment: Where did you intend the exponent of $1/2$ to be? Do you mean $\sqrt{\operatorname{Log}(z^4-1)}$ or $\operatorname{Log}\sqrt{z^4-1}$?

Comment: the second option Log [(z^4 - 1)^(1/2)]

Comment: You need to find regions where $\text{Re} (z^4-1)^\frac 12 > 0$, not just $(z^4-1)$. Same for Im.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I stupidly forgot the property of $Log$ function that allows to transfer the power as a factor. I'll try to clarify answer in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing fairly well. As for the inequality, find that polynomial's roots first:
$$
x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-1 = 0 \\
x^2 = 3y^2 \pm \sqrt{9y^4-y^4+1} = 3y^2 \pm \sqrt{8y^4+1} \\
x_{1,2,3,4} = \pm \sqrt { 3y^2 \pm \sqrt{8y^4+1}}
$$
So inequality can be rearranged as
$$
(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4) > 0
$$
As for the second region with $\text{Im} (z^4-1) \ne 0$ you didn't find all roots of that equation
$$
4x^3y-4xy^3=0 \\
4xy(x^2-y^2) = 0 \\
\left [ \begin{array}{l}
xy = 0 \\
x^2-y^2 =0
\end{array}
\right . \Longrightarrow \left [ \begin{array}{l}
\left [ \begin{array}{l}
x = 0, y \in \mathbb R \\
y = 0, x \in \mathbb R
\end{array}\right . \\
|x| = |y|
\end{array}
\right .
$$
So final regions looks like filled region below (white color means excluded points)

[image: region]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, just one question though, how are the polynomial roots (x1, x2, x3, x4) found, can it be done by hand, it seems very complicated.

Comment: It's not, actually. Equation is quadratic with respect to $x^2$, and then take sqrt of it.

Comment: So I understand how you got the equation to solve for the roots, but I don't see how you can use that to find x. Do I need a program like Matlab to solve it?

Comment: Alright, let's do it step by step
$$
x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-1=0 \\
x^2=u; y^2=v \\
u^2-6uv+v^2-1=0 \\
$$
So, $u$ is your unknown, $6v$ and $v^2-1$ are coefficients.
$$
D = 36v^2-4v^2+4=32v^2+4=4(8v^2+1) \\
u_{1,2} = \frac{6v \pm \sqrt{4(8v^2+1)}}2 = 3v \pm \sqrt{8v^2+1}
$$
Now, let's recall that $x^2=u$ and therefore $x = \pm \sqrt u$, so $x_{1,2,3,4}=\pm \sqrt{3v \pm \sqrt{8v^2+1}}$. Now recall that $v=y^2$, so final answer is
$$
x_{1,2,3,4} = \pm \sqrt{3y^2 \pm \sqrt{8y^4 + 1}}
$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I understand how you got the equation x1, x2, x3, x4. But what's the interpretation of this, do I just plug in values of y in ?

Comment: It defines all points where given equation is satisfied. It's the edge of filled region in the picture above.

Comment: Ok, forget about $(x-x_1)\ldots (x-x_4)>0$ part. Draw a line with the the equation $x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4-1=0$. If you solve it for $x$ you'll get $x_{1,2,3,4} = \ldots$ that I showed above, If you draw that line you'll get right and left branches in the picture. If you solve equation with respect to $y$ you'll find $y_{1,2,3,4} = \ldots$ function. If you plot that you'll get top and bottom branches. Now, take one point inside of each branch and check which inequality is satisfied - $\le 0$ or $\ge 0$. Because all other points inside of that branch will satisfy the same inequality.